# Should I go with react native with expo or I should eject it

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I have to create a small react native app with some charts and graphs I need to know should I go with [expo](https://expo.io/) or not. What challenges can I face if I continue with expo.

Answer (score 1):

i'm completely new to StackOverflow, but i have some experience in developing apps in react native, so far i have developed 6 apps(2 of them with expo) and they are already in play store/app store, my advice to the decision of whether to choose expo, eject, or go straight to react-native, is first of all evaluate what needs has the app that you are going to develop, all of them have their pros and cons, expo for example is super fast, you can have an app ready for production in weeks, to eject from expo is a very difficult thing to do, and to be honest i gave up on this and had to rebuild an entire project because i took the wrong decision on choosing expo, so i ended up rebuilding it in react native pure, now when i start a new project i tend to evaluate very deeply the needs of the project, review if expo is going to be enough for that needs. With React-Native pure projects you have the ease to add libs going straight to xcode, android and modifying directly there, and also have access to more native functionality.